# While opening silverlight application an exception occurs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight

In VS2010 I get the following error when opening a Silverlight application:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.SilverlightMetadataContext.SilverlightXamlExtensionImplementations.<GetXmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings>d__8.MoveNext()
at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.BuildSubsumption()
at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.SubsumingNamespace(Identifier identifier)
at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.BuildScope(PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context)
at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.ConvertToXaml(XamlElement parent, PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context, IMarkupSourceProvider provider)
at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.FullParse(Boolean convertToXamlWithErrors)
at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.get_RootItem()
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.Trees.ModifiableDocumentTree.get_ModifiableRootItem()
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.MarkupDocumentManagerBase.get_LoadState()
at MS.Internal.Host.PersistenceSubsystem.Load()
at MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load()
at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.Load()
at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedView.Load()
at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedDesignerFactory.Load(IsolatedView view)
at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.Load()
at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()
```

Now I want to say that on my PC Microsoft Silverlight, Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK and Microsoft Silverlight 4 SDK are all installed. In the project that I get this exception with I am using the Silverlight 3 SDK.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try deleting the project's `bin` and `obj` folders and rebuilding.  If there is still a problem, see if you can narrow it down to one or two XAML pages/codebehind files.  If you can narrow it down to a few files, edit your question to include the code you think is causing the problem in the VS designer.  Without this information we will not be able to reproduce your problem and hence not be able to help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

check the silverlight code in your xaml implementation code it seems that the variable d__8 is not populated or a null or not referenced ..

check this
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vswpfdesigner/thread/01ce533e-ed94-48d2-8184-e2e34e6bdc6f

Comment: Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.SilverlightMetadataContext.SilverlightXamlExtensionImplementations.<GetXmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings>d__8.MoveNext()

Comment: ok check this it might help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vswpfdesigner/thread/01ce533e-ed94-48d2-8184-e2e34e6bdc6f

Answer (score 0):

open *.csproj file with Notepad and check this lines:

```
<ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</ApplicationDefinition>
```

it must be exist in *.csproj file.

Comment: so what configuration I need to do over here?

Comment: yeah the configuration is same in the csproj file

Comment: install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1.     http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691